# Node express static files

Tags: node.js, express, static, server

I'm working with node and express. I try to create a simple server using express.static. I have a file in the following folder on my server :

```
client/index.html
```

However, when I try this url : http://myServer.com/index.html, the server answers that :

```
Cannot GET /index.html
```

Here, you will find my used code :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('client'));


/*
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});*/

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

My file index.html is available. I already used other way to keep this like by using

```
app.get('/index.html', function (req, res, next) {
  var options = {
    root: __dirname + '/client/',
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
        'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'x-sent': true
    }
  };

  res.sendFile("index.html", options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(err.status).end();
    }
    else {
      console.log('Sent:', "index.html");
    }
  });
});
```

And this approach works.

Comment: I tried your first block of code on my laptop and it worked just fine for me.  Are you sure you put the port number into the URL?

Comment: where'd you go Gonath?  You shouldn't just post a question and disappear.  StackOverflow doesn't work like some online forums where you throw out a question and then come back the next day.  Post a question and hang around here for a while and check back several times to see if people have questions, if you need to give them feedback on answers, etc...  StackOverflow works much better for all if you treat it as much more interactive than you are.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you were trying this URL:

http://myServer.com/index.html

But, your server is listening on port 8080, so you need to use this URL:

http://myServer.com:8080/index.html

or this:

http://myServer.com:8080

Because `express.static()` will automatically use `index.html` for the `/` path.

---

FYI, when I run your first block of code on my laptop with the proper URL, it works just fine.  The browser shows me the contents of client/index.html where "client" is a sub-directory below where my app.js file is run from to start the server.